# How to send message with url to twitter account through android applications?

Tags: android, twitter, message

I need to send a direct message with a URL link to the user's Twitter friends through Applications. The message is not successfully being sent with my current code:

```
 public void sendTwitterfriends()
 {
     HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
     HttpPost request = new HttpPost("https://api.twitter.com/1/direct_messages/new.format");
     List<NameValuePair> postParameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                    postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("user_id", "friendsuserid"));
      postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("text", "Hi Testing"));
      try {
          UrlEncodedFormEntity entity = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(postParameters);
          request.setEntity(entity);       
          HttpResponse response= httpClient.execute(request);
      }catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO: handle exception
      }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: What happens when you execute this?

Also, it's bad practice to catch `Exception`, you should manage each unique exception accordingly.